# ArduinoJson library: how much space to allocate for serialized buffer?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-mega

I am using the fantastic `ArduinoJson` library for working with JSON data on my ESP8266. I have been facing issues with **random software wdt resets** and have been investigating memory leaks wherever I can. I want to trim down my use of `Strings` and `DynamicJsonDocument`s as much as possible. So I thought of using automatic variables: char buffers: `char[N]` and `StatitcJsonDocument`s instead.

I am using the ArduinoJson assitant service to help me figure out how many bytes I should reserve. The following is one response payload, I am expecting to receive:

```
// char input[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH];

StaticJsonDocument<128> doc;

DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, input, MAX_INPUT_LENGTH);

if (error) {
  Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
  Serial.println(error.f_str());
  return;
}

int statusCode = doc["statusCode"]; // 200
bool needUpdate = doc["needUpdate"]; // true
const char* message = doc["message"]; // "update required"

JsonObject data = doc["data"];
const char* data_deviceId = data["deviceId"]; // "DLD00005"
const char* data_user_fw_version = data["user_fw_version"]; // "0.0.0"
const char* data_new_fw_version = data["new_fw_version"]; // "0.0.5"
```

As you can see I am using a `char [N]` type as the input, which is in fact being copied using `strncpy()` from the `https.getString().c_str()` from the response of a previous `https.POST()` request. My issue is that **I do not know how much memory I should reserve for the `char[N]` array**, ie what should be the value of `N`? The reasons I ask is that I am getting a `deserialization() failed: IncompleteInput` error, which I'm pretty sure is because the `char[N]` buffer is not large enough. So my question is if the StaticJsonDocument object is `128` bytes, then how big should I make the `char[N]` buffer (is there any relation between the sizes)? Or should I just go with an arbitrarily large value like `char[512]` which I want to avoid to avoid stack overflows?

```
StaticJsonDocument<128> payload;
char payloadSerial[???];  
...
int status = https.POST(payloadSerial);
strncpy(payloadSerial, https.getString().c_str(), sizeof(payloadSerial));
DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(payload, payloadSerial, sizeof(payloadSerial));
if (error) {
    Monitor.print(F("DeserializeJson() failed: "));
    Monitor.println(error.f_str());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about code that looks like this:

```
StaticJsonDocument<128> payload;
char payloadSerial[???];  
...
int status = https.POST(payloadSerial);
strncpy(payloadSerial, https.getString().c_str(), sizeof(payloadSerial));
DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(payload, payloadSerial, sizeof(payloadSerial));
```

The documentation for [`deserializeJson()`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/json/deserializejson/?cmdf=deserializeJson) shows that it can accept a `String` directly:

```
DeserializationError deserializeJson(JsonDocument& doc, const String& input);
```

So there's no need to copy `https.getString().c_str()` into `payloadSerial`. You can just pass the `String` that `https.getString()` returns:

```
StaticJsonDocument<128> payload;

int status = https.POST(request_body);

DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(payload, https.getString());
```

You were using the same character array here for both the body of the request that you passed to `POST()` and for deserializing the JSON response. While this is okay, for clarity I changed the `POST` call to use something else as the character array is completely unnecessary for processing the response.

Even if `deserializeJson()` didn't accept a `String` type as an argument, you still wouldn't need to copy the response into a buffer. You could just pass `https.getString().c_str()`:

```
StaticJsonDocument<128> payload;

int status = https.POST(request_body);

DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(payload, https.getString().c_str());
```

You **really** should check the value of `status`. It indicates whether the POST succeeded or not. If it failed, you should report that and the reason for the failure, and not attempt to process the returned payload as there is no returned payload.